# React not recognising an imported array

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a beginners React tutorial and I'm having an issue with this:

```
import React from "react";
import productsData from "./productsData";
import Product from "./Product";

function App() {
  const productComponents = productsData.map(product => {
    <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
  })

  return(
    <div>
      {productComponents}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The imported value `productsData` is just a JSON-style array of objects. If I put a debugger in before the map then `productsData` throws a not defined error. Yet if I do this:

```
import React from "react";
import productsData from "./productsData";
import Product from "./Product";

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Product product={productsData[0]} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Then it correctly displays the component based on the first object in the array.

Furthermore, in the debugger, there is a module named `_productsData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__` which contains the array I'm after, among other things.

My question is why can't I just access `productsData`?

Comment: How is producstsData exported from that file?

Comment: Your `.map` does not return anything. Either remove the `{}` or add `return`

Comment: @FranjoPintarić `export default productsData;`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Good shout, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in the first instance you are missing a return statement within your map function.  Since you have the map function in brackets, Javascript is looking for something to be returned to the array that the map function returns into `productComponents`.

The reason the second example works for you, is due to the fact that you are correctly returning the component.

I believe something like the below should work for you.

** Note the return keyword before your  component.

```js
const productComponents = productsData.map(product => {
    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
  });
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Also worth mentioning that @GabrielePetrioli suggested an alternative to the return which also works - removing the curly braces.

Comment: Yup.  Good catch @GabrielePetrioli .  I should have included that example.  Glad it works!